# How to use if else with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use if else with angular to filter the images from the controller. I am trying to show the image with my list if it exists and if not it show the placeholder image.I am new to angular can someone please guide.

I have tried some online solutions to use with it like

```
 <div *ngIf="{{item.icon}}; else templateName">
   <img ng-src = "{{item.icon}}" />
 </div>
 <ng-template #templateName>
    <img ng-src = "{{item.placeholderImage}}" />
  </ng-template>
```

I have created this component which I am trying to call in my index file. I am also not able to display the dates which was working before I transferred it in the component. I think there is something wrong with the commas.
`{{date | date:"EEE MMM dd yyyy"}}`

````
  module('cListApp').
  component('itemsList', {
    template:<ul> 
    <li class="list-body-container" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items"> 
        <div class="profileImage"> 

        </div> 
        <div class="list-body-left"> 
            <div class="li-title"><h2>{{item.name}}</h2><h4>Title3</h4></div> 
            <div class="li-body"><p>{{item.snippet}}</p></div> 
            <div class="li-date"> 
                <div id="calendar"> 
                    <div id="c-top"> 
                        <span id="l1"></span> 
                        <span id="l2"></span> 
                    </div> 
                    <div id="c-mark"></div> 
                </div> 
                {{date | date:"EEE MMM dd yyyy"}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-body-right">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>,
controller: function cListController() {
      this.items = [
        {
            name: 'Nexus S',
            snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
            icon: 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?image=491'
        }, {
            name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'

        }, 

      ],
      this.placeholderImage = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?blur',
      this.date = new Date();
    }
  });```
````

Comment: What is ng-src? Do you mean to use `[src]=“item.icon”`? To set src attribute to a dynamic value?

Comment: I think ng-src is the angular directive to show Image source in the application.
I think it may be similar to [src] i believe

Comment: `ng-src` is angularjs directive. `*ngIf` is angular directive. Looks like you're doing angularjs? Which should of been `ng-if`?

Comment: Please clarify what version of Angular you are specifically using.

Comment: I think I am using AngularJs 1.7.x

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ng-if`, simply use an expression:

> COMPLICATED
>
> ```
> <div>
>    <img ng-if="item.icon"   ng-src = "{{item.icon}}" />
>    <img ng-if="!item.icon"  ng-src = "{{$ctrl.placeholderImage}}" />
> </div>
> ```

Simpler

```
<img ng-src = "{{item.icon || $ctrl.placeholderImage}}" />
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: This is awesome in terms of simplicity. I was thinking of using a simple ternary but this beats it by miles :D :D

Comment: Thanks this does work with some modifications in the controller data object.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in angularJS and in angularJS there is no such thing as `ng-else` that is in angular. To make this work you can use `ng-if` or `ng-show` of angularJS.

```
<div>
   <img ng-if="item.icon"   ng-src = "{{item.icon}}" />
  <img ng-if="!item.icon"  ng-src = "{{item.placeholderImage}}" />
 </div>
```

What it will do is if icon is present first image will be shown with **item.icon** as image URL and if not condition in second **img** tag will be true and second one will be shown with placeholder image

Answer (score 1):

I have got this working via below expression.

`<img ng-src = "{{item.icon || item.placeholderImage}}" />`

However, I have to make few changes to the controller from where it shows the data

```
controller: function cListController() {
      this.items = [
        {
            name: 'Nexus S',
            snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
            icon: 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?image=491'
        }, {
            name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        }, 

      ],
      this.placeholderImage = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?blur',
      this.date = new Date();
    }
```

Instead it's outside of first array I have to put the placeholder image inside the array

```
{
 name: 'Nexus S',
 snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
 icon: 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?image=491'
},
{
  name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
  snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
  placeholderImage = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?blur',
},
```

Comment: If the placeholder is outside the array, use `<img ng-src = "{{item.icon || $ctrl.placeholderImage}}" />`. Or use a string literal, `<img ng-src = "{{item.icon || 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?blur'}}" />`